# How do I delete one of two Ubuntus on my PC

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, delete

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 two times on my PC. Each on a different partition. I would like to delete the one which I'm not using. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You could use OS-Uninstaller.

You can install it by running these in your terminal window.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller
os-uninstaller
```

Follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) link.

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot the Ubuntu installation that you want to keep.
2. Use your favourite partition manager (e. g. Gnome Disks, KDE Partition Manager, GParted) to delete or format the partition(s) associated with the Ubuntu installation that you want to remove. **This will destroy all the data on these partitions.**
3. Run `sudo update-grub` to update the boot entries in Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and overwrite the partition. (I recommend *GParted* for that job.)
Afterwards run `update-grub` to remove the deleted system out of GRUB's boot list.